# List Array of Days Between Two Dates

Tags: ruby

I would like to list an array of days between two dates. I can list an array of months with the code below. How might I change this to show every day between two dates?

```
require 'date'

date_from  = Date.parse('2011-05-14')
date_to    = Date.parse('2011-05-30')
date_range = date_from..date_to

date_months = date_range.map {|d| Date.new(d.year, d.month, 1) }.uniq
date_months.map {|d| d.strftime "%d/%m/%Y" }

puts date_months
```

Comment: Don't you have that already as `date_range`? If that is not what you want, then your question is not clear.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't know which day you meant, thus I have shown all the ways.

## [#wday](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-wday) is the day of week (0-6, Sunday is zero).

```
 (date_from..date_to).map(&:wday)
```

## [#mday](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-mday) is the day of the month (1-31).

```
(date_from..date_to).map(&:mday)
```

## [#yday](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-yday) is  the day of the year (1-366).

```
(date_from..date_to).map(&:yday)
```

OP's actual need was not much clear to me. After few comments between us, I came to know from [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071847/list-array-of-days-between-two-dates/26071852#comment40849613_26071852), the below answer OP is looking for -

```
(date_from..date_to).map(&:to_s)
```

Comment: OK this is a great start, so how would i automatically form it to the whole date (i.e. 2014-05-06, 2014-05-07, 2014-05-08)

Comment: would i just get the components of the date separately, then string them back together?

Comment: i guess what if its different months

Comment: so like from date is "2014-06-10" and end date is "2014-07-22"

Comment: Ok Then what you want from there.. ?

Comment: yes, i would like to be able to use the code to list between two dates, even if they are in a different month. So dates between 2014-10-29 and 2014-11-03 would be (2014-10-30, 2014-10-31, 2014-11-01, 2014-11-02).