# How to make integer into array of dates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, methods

If a user creates a challenge with `days_challenge: 5` & `committed: ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri"]` then how can we create an array of dates from `date_started: "2016-04-20"` until the last day of the challenge using a model method called `dates_challenged`?

```
create_table "challenges", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "action"
  t.date     "date_started"
  t.text     "committed",       default: "---\n- sun\n- mon\n- tue\n- wed\n- thu\n- fri\n- sat\n"
  t.integer  "days_challenged"
end
```

The array would look something like this: `["2016-04-20", "2016-04-21", "2016-04-22", "2016-04-25", "2016-04-26"]`

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :committed, Array

  def dates_challenged
    # Not sure if a model method is enough or if I'd have to migrate a new column
  end

  def committed_wdays
    committed.map do |day|    
      Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize)
    end
  end

  def days_left_challenged
    def days_done_challenged
      ((date_started.to_date)..Date.yesterday).count do |date| 
        committed_wdays.include? date.wday
      end
    end  
    if self.days_done_challenged >= self.days_challenged
      0
    else
      self.days_challenged - ((date_started.to_date)..Date.yesterday).count do |date| 
        committed_wdays.include? date.wday
      end
    end
  end
end
```

To clarify, I'm trying to make a model method so I could do `@challenge.dates_challenged` in a view where I can then iterate over the array of dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with - there are still some issues - I think it will blow up if `committed` is empty, but it's nice and concise:

```
def dates_challenged
  date = date_started-1
  days_challenge.times.map { date = find_next(date) }
end

private
def find_next(date)
  break if committed.include? Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES[date.wday].downcase while date = date.next
  date
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the start date and end date - then you can get a range of dates and or days between the start and the end

```
start_date = challenge.date.to_date
end_date   = another_challenge.date.to_date
(start_date..end_date).map(&:mday) # returns array of days of the month
```

see [List Array of Days Between Two Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071847/list-array-of-days-between-two-dates) for more information

Comment: Part of the complexity of the question is how do you get the end date? Thanks though if I'm able to create the method on my own using the info for the answer I'll give you credit :]

Comment: do you want the challenge with the most current date?

Comment: I'm trying to create an array of dates using a method `dates_challenged`. I give an example of what that would output if `date_started` was today, `days_challenged` was 5, and `committed` was weekdays. Hope that is clearer. Sorry not too clear on your question.

Comment: perhaps you can revise your question to convey intent a little clearer and simpler? it is hard for me to tell what you need here

Comment: Updated question. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
committed = ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri"]
days = committed.dup

count = 0
dates = []

while days.present?
    count += 1
    weekday = (date + count).strftime('%a').downcase
    if days.include? weekday
        dates << (date + count.days).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        days.delete(weekday)
    end
end

puts dates # => ["2016-04-21", "2016-04-22", "2016-04-25", "2016-04-26", "2016-04-27"]
```

---

**Previuos answer**

Assuming you are in Rails environment:

```
days_challenge = 5
date           = DateTime.parse("2016-04-20")

(1..days_challenge).map {|n| (date + n.days).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }

# Outputs
["2016-04-21", "2016-04-22", "2016-04-23", "2016-04-24", "2016-04-25"]
```

Comment: Yea I'm trying to create a method `dates_challenged` in rails. Thanks for trying to help me out again. Problem with the output though. That shows 5 days in a row. The example I gave uses `committed` days, which didn't include weekends.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks U! I'm trying to make a method though so I could do `@challenge.dates_challenged` where then I can iterate over the array of dates in a view. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and verbose:  create a date object from your date string (Date.parse), and create an empty array to hold the dates that you are 'committing' to.  The list of days of the week that are available is stored in an array, as above. Loop until the number of days we are committing to stored in the array is equal to how many days were requested, adding one day to each previous day.  Dates added to the date_committed array are checked against the valid days of week array (days_committed).

```
require 'date'

days_challenge = 5
days_committed = ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri"] 
date_started = "2016-04-20"
date_committed = []
date_started_parsed = Date.parse(date_started)

while (date_committed.size < days_challenge)
  date_dow = date_started_parsed.strftime('%a').downcase
  if (days_committed.include?(date_dow))
    date_committed << date_started_parsed.strftime('%F')
  end # if
  date_started_parsed = date_started_parsed + 1
end # while

puts date_committed.to_s
```

Returns the correct dates based on valid days of the week.

```
["2016-04-20", "2016-04-21", "2016-04-22", "2016-04-25", "2016-04-26"]
```